# How to change tensor image dimensions with a manually defined class in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a manually defined class to load images in Tensorflow 2.

```
class MasterImage0(object):

    def __init__(self,PATH='', IMAGE_SIZE = 128):
        self.PATH = PATH
        self.IMAGE_SIZE = IMAGE_SIZE

        self.image_data = []
        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []
        self.CATEGORIES = []

        # This will get List of categories
        self.list_categories = []

    def get_categories(self):
        for path in os.listdir(self.PATH):
            if '.DS_Store' in path:
                pass
            else:
                self.list_categories.append(path)
        print("Found Categories ",self.list_categories,'\n')
        return self.list_categories

    def process_image(self):
        try:
            """
            Return Numpy array of image
            :return: X_Data, Y_Data
            """
            self.CATEGORIES = self.get_categories()
            for categories in self.CATEGORIES:                                                  # Iterate over categories

                train_folder_path = os.path.join(self.PATH, categories)                         # Folder Path
                class_index = self.CATEGORIES.index(categories)                                 # this will get index for classification

                for img in os.listdir(train_folder_path):                                       # This will iterate in the Folder
                    new_path = os.path.join(train_folder_path, img)                             # image Path

                    try:        # if any image is corrupted
                        image_data_temp = cv2.imread(new_path)                 # Read Image as numbers
                        image_temp_resize = cv2.resize(image_data_temp,(self.IMAGE_SIZE,self.IMAGE_SIZE))
                        self.image_data.append([image_temp_resize,class_index])
                        random.shuffle(self.image_data)
                    except:
                        pass

            data = np.asanyarray(self.image_data)

            # Iterate over the Data
            for x in data:
                self.x_data.append(x[0])        # Get the X_Data
                self.y_data.append(x[1])        # get the label

            X_Data = np.asarray(self.x_data) / (255.0)      # Normalize Data
            Y_Data = np.asarray(self.y_data)
            
            # reshape x_Data

            X_Data = X_Data.reshape(-1, self.IMAGE_SIZE, self.IMAGE_SIZE, 3)
            print("Compiled X_data", self.X_data)
            return X_Data, Y_Data
        except:
            print("Failed to run Function Process Image ")

    def pickle_image(self):

        """
        :return: None Creates a Pickle Object of DataSet
        """
        # Call the Function and Get the Data
        X_Data,Y_Data = self.process_image()

        # Write the Entire Data into a Pickle File
        pickle_out = open('X_Data','wb')
        pickle.dump(X_Data, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

        # Write the Y Label Data
        pickle_out = open('Y_Data', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(Y_Data, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

        print("Pickled Image Successfully ")
        return X_Data,Y_Data
        print(self.X_Data)

    def load_dataset(self):

        try:
            # Read the Data from Pickle Object
            X_Temp = open('..\SeekThermal\X_Data','rb')
            X_Data = pickle.load(X_Temp)

            Y_Temp = open('..\SeekThermal\Y_Data','rb')
            Y_Data = pickle.load(Y_Temp)

            print('Reading Dataset from Pickle Object')

            return X_Data,Y_Data

        except:
            print('Could not Found Pickle File ')
            print('Loading File and Dataset  ..........')

            X_Data,Y_Data = self.pickle_image()
            print("X_data", self.X_Data)
            return X_Data,Y_Data
```

So I can load my training images like this and the shape of my tensor is `100*100*3`.

```
a = MasterImage0(PATH = path_train,IMAGE_SIZE = 128)
#a.load_dataset()
(train_images, train_labels) = a.load_dataset() 

print(train_images.shape 
Out: (4732, 100, 100, 3)
```

The original image size is 300x400 pixels. I do not understand why I cannot change the the tensor shape to 128 instead of 100, for example. I thought I could do it by setting IMAGE_SIZE = 128?
Where does it take the 100 from? thank you.

Comment: the load_dataset function is just doing pickle.load. Where is it setting image size to 128? It will just load the data as it was dumped in the file. Ideally you should be using numpy.save and load.

Comment: how can I use numpy save and load here? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.resize()` and `np.array.reshape()` must work correctly, if they did not work, they would throw exception, but obviously, no exception was thrown here, only just your setting `IMAGE_SIZE=128` did not work.

So, here the problem is most likely caused by using `pickle`, which cached your codes' buffer (all resized and reshaped images) at the first time and reuesd it again when you re-run your codes.

If so, I suspect that you must have set `IMAGE_SIZE=100` once, cached all `(*,100,100,3)` results, and here when you run by setting `IMAGE_SIZE=128`, the cached(pickled) file (`(*,100,100,3)` size files) will just be returned, leading to this problem.

You can delete all cached files in `..\SeekThermal` and try again
or
rewrite `try` part of func `load_dataset` like the following to give each cached file a `stamp`

```py
...
        try:
            # Read the Data from Pickle Object
            X_Temp = open(f'..\SeekThermal\X_Data_{self.IMAGE_SIZE}','rb')
            X_Data = pickle.load(X_Temp)

            Y_Temp = open(f'..\SeekThermal\Y_Data_{self.IMAGE_SIZE}','rb')
            Y_Data = pickle.load(Y_Temp)

            print('Reading Dataset from Pickle Object')

            return X_Data,Y_Data
...
```

Comment: it is throwing an exception ("Could not Found Pickle File") because FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\SeekThermal\\X_Data_128'   with this code. but I can see what you mean, thank you!